# What does ^= mean in set command?

Tags: register

I had seen a set command in `.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus
```

What does `^=` mean in set command?What is the difference between
`set clipboard^=unnamed,unnamedplus`

and

`set clipboard=unnamed,unnamedplus`
?

Comment: `:help ^=<Tab>` is a great way to find these things out! That autocompletes to `:help set^=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because clipboard is a string option, it means Vim should [prepend the value to the existing value](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%3Aset%5E%3D) (whereas a plain `:set option=` would overwrite the existing value entirely).

For some options you can also do `:set option+=`, but [that doesn't work for `'clipboard'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27clipboard%27) because if one of the existing items is `exclude:` then you can't add an item after that.

When used with a number option, it multiplies the existing value instead.

See [`:help :set^=`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%3Aset%5E%3D) for more details.

Comment: Good answer, but perhaps it would be useful to also show the relevant help command? I.e. `:help :set^=` - it may help more people learn to find answers from the docs...

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg It was in an earlier version, but I edited it out. I think you're right though: I've added it back in.